# How can I take use of nav2d.js

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have read almost all of it,but it is hard to get the result.As is shown in the example,
var nav = new Nav2D({  ros : ros,
canvasID : "nav"
});
It can create an object successfully,but the function draw() in the nav2d.js has not been called,so there will not be any picture in the browser.Is there any correct example? I hope someone can help me,thank you.

Gerald

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49661/how-can-i-take-use-of-nav2d.js/) by [Gerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3133/gerald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To change map size, an easy way is to run the example file /example/nav2d.html, where you could change the canvas size.

---

Originally posted by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) with karma: 393 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2